# Instagram : who viewed my profile

Tags: php, instagram

Is there any way to determining profile visitors in Instagram?
if answer is no, how [this app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/who-viewed-my-profile-for/id1026603103?mt=8) doing this.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to determining profile visitors in Instagram?

No. There is no sign of anything that would allow that in the [API documentation](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints)

> if answer is no, how this app doing this.

It appears to generate fake data in order to scam people.

Comment: the rating of this app is more than 4 and more than 4706  people rated this app, so i think it is not possible if application was fake.

Comment: There is a thriving industry in selling positive reviews. If you're going to scam people with fake data, then you're not going to be above buying astroturfed reviews. https://www.macstories.net/news/website-sells-positive-itunes-reviews-for-your-apps/ & http://techcrunch.com/2009/08/22/cheating-the-app-store-pr-firm-has-interns-post-positive-reviews-for-clients/

Answer (score 4):

From the page itself:

> InstaView calculates all your Instagram activity and get data for each users who has interacted with you recently.

You can't really tell what this app actually "calculates". Beside that it says "most accurate way to find out Who Viewed Your Profile" which shows that determining the exact amount probably isn't possible at all ..